# CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

Tags: blazor-server-side

> I'm working on blazor serever project using .NET 3.1 but am getting an error "CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to 'Employeemanagement.Models.Employee'  EmployeeManagement.Web".

Here is my code:

```
 public async Task<Employee> UpdateEmployee(Employee updatedEmployee)
    {
        return await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync<Employee>("api/employees", updatedEmployee);
    }
```

[Screenshot of my code showing an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03EfM.png)

Comment: As stated in the error and the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.putasjsonasync?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1), `httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync()` returns a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`, but you defined that the function must return `Task<Employee>`, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your method must return `Task<Employee>`, instead is returning `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`.

Try this:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateEmployee(Employee updatedEmployee)
 {
     return await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync<Employee>("api/employees", updatedEmployee);
 }
```